# How to diagonally split a cell, and fill in text on both parts in a spreadsheet using python ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe with made up values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country|Gender': ["US", "UK", "Canada"],
                   'Male': [100000, 10000, 1000],
                   'Female': [200000, 20000, 2000]})
```

Now I am put it to an excel:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
output_file='output.xlsx'
writer = ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'FirstSheet', index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I want to split the top-left cell of the dataframe on the spreadsheet diagonally, with `"Country"` in the bottom while `"Gender"` on the top.

How can I do that?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know how to diagonally split a cell with the (pd.)excelwriter.

Comment: Obviously, or you wouldn't be here.  How did you *try* to solve this problem?

Comment: This is beyond what pandas can do.  Excel doesn't have a "split the cell diagonally" feature.  You can simulate that by drawing a diagonal border and creating a two-line cell value with tricky formatting, but there's no simple "diagonal split" command.

Comment: ^^^ It may help to attempt this manually first, and only then translate to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can tweak the split with the [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter) engine you already set :

```
with ExcelWriter(output_file, engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, "FirstSheet", index=False)
    
    ws = writer.sheets["FirstSheet"]
    wb = writer.book

    fmt = wb.add_format({"diag_type": 2, "diag_color": "black"})
    fmt.set_text_wrap()
    fmt.set_border(1)
    fmt.set_bold()

    ws.write("A1", "{}Gender\nCountry".format(" "*15), fmt)
    ws.set_row(0, 29)
    ws.set_column("A:A", 13)
```

Output (*output.xlsx*):

[image]